# Batch scripting Return result into a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a generic script that will parse a statement and return the result. I have done so in shell, but don't know how this can happen in batch scripting

Script 1 Main script (main.bat).

```
SET Myresult=CALL child.bat "Statement"
```

Now `Myresult` should store the answer whatever I want to return in this variable.

Solution 1 : SET Myresult in Child.bat and use it in main.bat but now what if the user does not know what the variable name is .

So is their a way to return a value like in java 
return xyz

xyz gets captured in the call statement elsewhere.

-------------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----------

PART 2

Here are the details of what I am doing .

The so called child script is getSQLResult.bat

What is does is

```
getSQLResult.bat -q "Select a from abc"
```

Now this above call statement can be used by anyone any how in any batch script .

So apart from passing a variablename(return name) or writing a for loop to parse the result set is there any simple straight forward way .

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** - Pass the variable name

main.bat

```
call child.bat myresult "Statement"
echo %myresult%
```

child.bat

```
set "%~1=argument was %~2"
```

**Option 2** - Process output of child process

main.bat

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('child.bat "Statement"') do set "myresult=%%a"
echo %myresult%
```

child.bat

```
@echo off
echo Argument was %~1
```

or you can use temporary files, the registry, the clipboard, ... to pass the information, but in any case if you are coding a element (your `child.bat`) to be reused by you or another person, you are creating an interface between this element and the rest of the code, a expected set of input arguments and a way to return information. Your question

> ... what if the user does not know what the variable name is?

is answered by the documentation of this interface.

Comment: Thnks MC ND but my question is a bit different .check out the edited question part2

Comment: @jjames, I've readed the modification. The statement execution will generate from `0` to `n` output lines. Environment variables content is limited to 8191 characters. The option to store the result into a variable is not safe/robust/convenient. Best option is to send statement execution to stdout from child and use the `for /f` in parent to process the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it in batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo hello world') do set myresult=%%a
echo it returned: %myresult%
```

(`echo hello world` is just an example)

Note: this will return the last (or only) line only. It can be modified to process more lines, but your example implies, there is only one line of output)

**EDIT** If I understand your edit correct, you want to pass just a statement to an external batchfile, which does the work and gives back the result into a variable, which is defined with the call.

```
REM child.bat
@echo off
set var=%1
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ("%*") do (
  set var=%%i
  set statement="%%~j"
)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('getSQLResult.bat -q  %statement%') do set "%var%=%%a"
```

use it with:

```
call child.bat result "Select a from abc"
echo %result%
```

of course it will still return the last (or only) line. Can be easily modified to get the first line. If the output could be more lines, I suggest using an "array" with an counter to avoid the problems, `MC ND` adresses in his comment to your question. Maybe returning a filename to a file with the multiline output could be another solution.